# "No space left on device" reported; trying to transfer files to EFS through EC2 instance via SCP

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress, scp, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

My setup is based on this article: https://parall.ax/blog/view/3212/how-to-run-scalable-wordpress-on-aws-amazon-web-services-tutorial

I.e. Wordpress hosting via Elastic Beanstalk with a separate RDS instance and and handling file serving/uploads via Elastic Filesystem. My `efs.config` is as such:

```
packages:
  yum:
    nfs-utils: []
    jq: []
files:
  "/tmp/mount-efs.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      mkdir -p /mnt/efs
      EFS_NAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.EFS_NAME')
      mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $EFS_NAME:/ /mnt/efs || true
      mkdir -p /mnt/efs/uploads
      chown webapp:webapp /mnt/efs/uploads
commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "/tmp/mount-efs.sh"
container_commands:
  01-rm-wp-content-uploads:
    command: rm -rf /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads
  02-symlink-uploads:
    command: ln -snf /mnt/efs/uploads /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads
```

I trying to use scp to transter around 400G of files to EFS through one one the EC2 instances. Specifically I am transferring the files to "/mnt/efs/uploads", which should be the mounted  EFS drive. However, after transferring around 7G, I am inevitably told "No space left on device."

Furthermore:

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXX-31-29-XXX uploads]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.9G   60K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.7G     0 100% /
```

Why am I getting this message? It seems like I am filling up the EC2 space, but I should just be putting the files on the EFS mounted on the EC2... thoughts?

Comment: That df output doesn't actually seem to show that you have an EFS endpoint mounted. Seems like you're just putting the files on the EC2 filesystem.

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion I came to as well. But how can "/mnt/efs/uploads" be on the EC2 file system?

Comment: Any reason you're using EFS instead of S3? There are Wordpress plugins that will put all uploads (typically pictures / videos) which will serve them directly. You can go via CloudFront as well to accelerate them.

Comment: `|| true` (i.e. "pretend success") at the end of the mount command seems more than a little bit wrong.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot better way to not try to mount if already mounted?

Comment: @two7s_clash test whether it is mounted: `if mount | grep fs-a1b2c3d4; then echo "yay"; else echo "boo"; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute */tmp/mount-efs.sh* script manually while connected via SSH to your instance and check if it returns any error.
Most likely the issue is in this line which failed to mount /mnt/efs directory to EFS:

```
      mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $EFS_NAME:/ /mnt/efs || true
```

Comment: seems like my script needed to be launched with "sudo" as apparently this command was denied with insufficient permissions.